# Bash: how to exclude files with .sh extensions using find?

Tags: bash, find

Good afternoon. My script should find files with the size less than the second argument ($fsize). At the same time it should ignore files with .sh extension. (Actually, it shouldn't find file of the running script. If you prompt me how to realize it, it would me excellent). So could you help me? Here is my vision of this, but it doesn't work.

```
find -type -f -size -$fsize -and -not -name *.sh
```

Comment: In what way does this not work? You probably want to quote `'*.sh'` to prevent the shell from expanding the glob (more than one `*.sh` file in the current directory and `find` will complain at you when this happens).

Comment: I mean that  script doesn't run. Bash writes "find: paths must precede the expression not". Then I tried  to place the directory once again before 'not'. Now it writes "find: paths must precede expression . ". Maybe this clarification will help you.

Comment: Yeah. That's the glob being expanded by the shell. (That's the complaining I was talking about.)

Comment: You need to put the directory where to search as the first argument after find. E.g: `find /tmp -f -size -"${fsize}" -and -not -name '*.sh'`.

Comment: @steviethecat: You don't need to do that if you don't want to specify such a path (it defaults to '.') - but if you add something later in the line that looks like the path, `find` will remind you to put it first.

Comment: @Micheal Jaros: I did not know that you could leave out the path, though is still consider it good practice to put the path explicitly as first argument.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
find ./ -type f -size -$fsize -and -not -name '*.sh'
```

Comment: Sorry, but the message is "find: paths must precede the expression not"

Comment: @MichaelPister : added ./ as path

Comment: Leaving the path to search off is a GNU find feature I believe.

Comment: Quote the variable too: `-size "-$fsize"`